# How to look for consecutive repeats in regex?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find matches where an alphanumeric character is repeated consecutively. I am trying `re.match("(\w)[\\1][\\1]",mystring)` but it doesn't seem to work (always returns None). I am trying to say "whatever alphanumeric letter is captured in the parentheses, check if it occurs twice in a row anywhere."

Comment: Note that `re.search` is pretty much the same as `re.match` except that `re.match` only matches at the beginning of the string, whereas `re.search` matches anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close enough :)

You can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) or [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match):

```
mystring = 'abccd'
print re.findall(r'(\w)\1', mystring)  # ['c']
```

The reason you fail to do so with [`match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match) is that `match` tries to find a matching from the beginning of the string and there is no such pattern `"(\w)[\\1][\\1]"` in the beginning of the string.

If you want to use `match` you can still do so, but it requires additional access to the captured group:

```
mystring = 'abccd'
m = re.match(r'.*(\w)\1', mystring)  
print m.group(1)  # 'c'
```

Comment: What is wrong with the way I had it? How is `".*(\w)\1.*"` different / working?

Comment: @user54089 two things: 1. see the correction to the regex and second is the use of `match`. See the last part of the answer.

Comment: Is there no way to do this using match? Only findall?

Comment: @user54089 yes you can, I added it to the answer

Comment: Is the "^" necessary in the match if you said it always looks from the beginning anyway? Other than that it makes sense to me, but what purpose does the two periods serve?

Comment: @user54089 indeed you don't have to use the `^`, I put it there out of habit (now removed). The reason for `.*` is to allow any number of other characters before the match. `.` is a "jocker" which can replace any character and `*` allows any number `.` >= 0

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
import re
test='abcaabbccaaa123333333'
print re.findall(r'(([a-zA-Z0-9])\2+)', test)
```

Prints:

```
[('aa', 'a'), ('bb', 'b'), ('cc', 'c'), ('aaa', 'a'), ('3333333', '3')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> pat = re.compile(r'(\w)\1')
>>> pat.findall('1234456678')
['4', '6']
```

you were very close but reminder that using `[]` means to capture anything inside of that `[]` brackets so `[\\1]` would match the literal characters `\` and `1`. also, if you repeated it twice, it would try and find triples since the first group is counted as the first occurence.

This will only match doubles BTW, if you want to match ANY amounts of repeats, add a `+` token at the end of the regex